# Copy Paste not working for plots in spyder

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder

I recently switched from Windows 10 to Linux-Fedora, to be more accurate. I normally mainly use the matplotlib module. Today, I wanted to copy a plot I had in the plot panel in Spyder, and it didn't work. I can do Ctrl+C - or click "Copy image", it won't help. Once I go on say a conversation where I want to paste the plot - it doesn't do anything. I'd like to know if someone could help me...

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Spyder will let you copy but not paste  within Spyder, unless you paste your copied plot  somewhere else , so try pasting it somewhere else ( like notepad ) then pasting it into spyder .

Comment: When I used Win10, I could copy the plot and e.g paste it into Twitter. With Linux-Fedora - I can't. It selects the plot, but it won't paste, not anywhere.